# Powershell move songs to Artist folder

Tags: bash, sorting, powershell

I have folders in folders in folders full of music I wanted to make it easy for me by putting all the music files from the same artist in the same folder but this would take days doing it manually... 
Expl: All the Elvis music goes into the Elvis folder can be created by me or with a script (creating a folder is easy) and this process goes on for the rest of my music files with other artist...
I don't know if it is possible to use the file details "artist tab" to sort this?

I Tried the Move-Item but no succes

any advice?

greetings

Answer (score 0):

This seems to not work, but it does a lot of the work that you are looking for.  http://www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-powershell-script-to-sort-music-from-folder-to-library/

Answer (score 0):

i use this module and dll for that sort of work:

http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2011/01/25/reading-and-writing-tags-to-videos-and-music.aspx